# Updating gcc 4.8 arm cross compiler to 4.9 on Mint 17.2

Tags: linux-mint, ubuntu-14.04, compile, gcc

While cross compiling a linux kernel (4.1) using gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf on Mint 17.2 (equivalent to Ubuntu 14.04 trusty) I get an error:

```
Your compiler is too buggy; it is known to miscompile kernels
```

The version of gcc I am using is 4.8.2. I'd gladly move to 4.9 but I'm not sure how to. There are updated toolchain PPA (eg: ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa) but I believe those are native only, not cross compile. There appear to be 4.9 gcc armhf builds for Ubuntu, but not on trusty - only on utopic and later.

Is there a reasonable way to pull a gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf package (and dependencies) for 4.9? Can I pull packages for utopic somehow?

Comment: One way appears to be to give up and go backwards rather than forwards: "sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf". This doesn't create the links for gcc, cpp, gcov so I did those manually.

Comment: Check the changlog in the gcc-4.8 packages. You might find that that bug has been fixed. If so, you can just disable the check in the kernel (not sure how).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Larrylisky](http://larrylisky.com/tag/ubuntu-14-04/):

It is a little arduous but you can download and install it manually.

> wget -c https://releases.linaro.org/archive/14.09/components/toolchain/binaries/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux.tar.xz
>
> tar xf gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux.tar.xz
>
> export CC=`pwd`/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-

Comment: As I asked about moving forward (rather than back which is what I eventually did - I hadn't time to investigate properly), I think this a reasonable answer.

Comment: Page no longer exists.